# Matrix of strings in C (similar as Matlab)

Tags: arrays, c, char

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to create a table in which each component contains a table of characters.
I know the code I'm going to put in is wrong, but I mean something like this

```
txt[1] = "ASD";
txt[2] = "FF";
txt[3] = "S43";
txt[4] = "ASF";
```

Thank you so much for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an array of arrays

```
array[size][size]
```

Next first positon

```
strcpy(array[0], "HELLO");
strcpy(array[1], "HY");
```

You can make a table, you just need to use the line and column that you want

```
array[line][column]
```

For example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
int main(){
    char array[100][256];

    strcpy(array[0], "HELLO");
    strcpy(array[1], "HY");

    printf("%s\n%s\n", array[0], array[1]);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Imagine that you inser the words that you want on scanf, the array[0] will have the first entire word, and so.

Comment: And how can I initialize this variable?

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezSuárez `char array[100][100]`, the 100 its just a example, number of line x columns

Comment: But I get an error if I write

`int main()
{    
    char array[100][100];
    array[0] = "HELLO";
    array[1] = "HY";
    
    return 0;
}`

Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezSuárez Pls edit your code using the right format to coding!

Comment: Yes I promise that I'm trying, thank you so much for all, the example was perfect!.

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezSuárez Check my answer updated and see my example, you cant match an array like that! You need a pointer! But for you case my example works